# clamav freshclam did not working

Tags: scanner, clamav

```
sudo freshclam
```

output:

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = 
/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!
```

Answer (score 9):

You're getting this error because the `clamav-freshclam` service is running in the background.

1. Stop it by typing `sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam.service` in a terminal.
2. Do the manual update afterwards by typing `sudo freshclam`.
3. Stop `clamav-freshclam` from starting automatically on system startup by executing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam` and configuring it for manual updates only, in the corresponding question.

By configuring `clamav-freshclam` this way, you will be able to select an update server that's closer to you so that it works faster and you will also be able to stop `freshclam` from giving an error concerning the `clamd.conf` file everytime it updates `clamav`, by disabling the `clamd` daemon notification.